# Uploading profile pictures once (not twice) into database, and displaying them correctly

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I am trying to built an option unto my site where users can upload a profile picture, so far so good, but the data is saved again and again in my database(table) when I refresh the page

++ the image doesn't show, it just shows a black square. 
Thanks for any help, as you can see,  I'm still an absolute beginner learning eagerly and ferociously

```
$images = (isset ($_FILES['images']['name']));
$paths= [];


if ($images)
{
    $saveto = "uploads/$user.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
    $typeok = TRUE;
    $paths[] = $saveto;
    $date1=date("Y-m-d h:m:s");

    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vlindr");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"imageupload"); //database connectivity

    mysqli_query($link,"insert into images 
                                (images_id, images_path, submission_date) 
                        VALUES (NULL,'$user','$date1')")
        or die(mysqli_error($link));

    switch($_FILES['images']['type'])
    {
        case "image/gif":   $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;
        case "image/jpeg":  // Both regular and progressive jpegs
        case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;
        case "image/png":   $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;
        default:            $typeok = FALSE; break;
    }

    if ($typeok)
    {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);

        $max = 150;
        $tw  = $w;
        $th  = $h;

        if ($w > $h && $max < $w) {
            $th = $max ;
            $tw = $max;
        }
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h) {
            $tw = $max / $h * $w;
            $th = $max;
        }
        elseif ($max < $w)           {
            $tw = $th = $max;
        }

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
        imageconvolution($tmp,  array(array(-1, -1, -1),
                                array(-1, 16, -1), 
                                array(-1, -1, -1)),
                         8, 0);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);
    }
}
```

Comment: The image doesn't show up correctly because you're inserting the wrong variable in your database instead of `$user` it should be `$saveto`

Comment: And where is `$user` set to a value?

Comment: The $user is set on the header.php page ( on top of the profile.php i have require_once 'header.php') it is set to


  if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
    $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
    $loggedin = TRUE;
    $userstr  = " ($user)";
  }
  else $loggedin = FALSE;

  echo "<title>$appname</title> etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if the code below works.
I also recommend prepared statements, although the code below is not the neatest it will get the job done!

```
$images = (isset ($_FILES['images']['name']));
$paths= [];


if ($images)
{
$saveto = "uploads/$user.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
$typeok = TRUE;
$paths[] = $saveto;
$date1=date("Y-m-d h:m:s");

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vlindr");
mysqli_select_db($link,"imageupload"); //database connectivity

//Checks if Image already exists in database
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE images_path=(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$saveto);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
//If the amount of rows returned is zero, the script will insert the image into the database
if($stmt->num_rows === 0) {

    //Inserts the image into the database
    $stmt2 = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images (images_id,images_path,submission_date) VALUES (NULL,?,?)");
    $stmt2->bind_param("ss",$saveto,$date1);
    if($stmt2->execute()) {
        echo "Image is unique and uploaded to database";
    }

    switch($_FILES['images']['type'])
    {
        case "image/gif":   $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;
        case "image/jpeg":  // Both regular and progressive jpegs
        case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;
        case "image/png":   $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;
        default:            $typeok = FALSE; break;
    }

    if ($typeok)
    {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);

        $max = 150;
        $tw  = $w;
        $th  = $h;

        if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
        {
            $th = $max ;
            $tw = $max;
        }
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
        {
            $tw = $max / $h * $w;
            $th = $max;
        }
        elseif ($max < $w)
        {
            $tw = $th = $max;
        }

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
        imageconvolution($tmp, array(array(-1, -1, -1),
            array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);

    }

}//end if
else {
    echo "Image Already Exists";
}//end else
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly, at first I got a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, but I added a bracket ( } ) after the last else statement, that solved it for me. Thanks alot You Sir

Comment: Ah I should've seen I missed a bracket for the if statement, apologies! I would like to highly recommend prepared statements https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp as it gives you more secure queries and better code.